# How to select twice the same column on join query?

Tags: google-bigquery

How Can I to count the gender when is M or F, somehting like

[image]

```
SELECT count(N.gender) 
FROM `DATABASE_T`   as T
LEFT JOIN `DATABASE_N` as N
ON 
T.ENCUESTA = N.ENCUESTA AND
T.P_DEPTO = N.P_DEPTO AND
T.P_MUNIC = N.P_MUNIC AND
T.COD_VEREDA = N.COD_VEREDA AND
T.PAIS = N.PAIS and
T.UC_UO = N.UC_UO

WHERE  N.ID_PROD=1 and N.gender="M"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT countif(N.gender = 'M') as M, countif(N.gender = 'F') as F
FROM `DATABASE_T`   as T
LEFT JOIN `DATABASE_N` as N
ON 
T.ENCUESTA = N.ENCUESTA AND
T.P_DEPTO = N.P_DEPTO AND
T.P_MUNIC = N.P_MUNIC AND
T.COD_VEREDA = N.COD_VEREDA AND
T.PAIS = N.PAIS and
T.UC_UO = N.UC_UO

WHERE  N.ID_PROD=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not describe the structure of your table and use Spanish-looking identifiers, I will use a clearer example with my own schema:

```
SELECT
   SUM( CASE WHEN Sex = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS M,
   SUM( CASE WHEN Sex = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS F
FROM  People
WHERE People.Dept = 5
```